# Get line feed with getch in Ruby

Tags: ruby, console, getch

I have the following code:

```
require 'io/console'
loop do
  character = STDIN.getch
  break if character == "\n"
  print "*"
end
```

The code is working, but I have to press the Enter key then *another key* to break the loop. Why? I have this issue only with the line feed.

Comment: For me it loops forever. If I add a `puts "<#{character.inspect}>"` after `character = STDIN.getch`, it displays `*<"\r">`. So pressing Enter (on my Mac) generates a Carriage Return, not a NewLine. The loop exits if `break if character == "\r"`.

Comment: On Windows, it generates a Line feed, not a Carriage return. I forgot it was platform dependent.