# Thread ignoring first input when using getch

Tags: ruby, multithreading, stdin, getch

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'io/console'

flag = 0
t2 =Thread.new do
    puts flag
    loop do
        temp = STDIN.getch
        if temp=="\n"
            flag = (flag+1)%2
            puts flag
        end
    end
end

# => Some foreground code

t2.join
```

When i run the code i get the value of `flag` printed `0` as it should. But the thread does not change the value of `flag` on the **first** <kbd>Enter</kbd> I hit. Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> the second time changes flag to `1` although. The thread works normally toggling the value of `flag` on further <kbd>Enter</kbd> hits. Why is this happening? What have I done wrong?

**Problem seems to be only with `getch`**
as when I use `gets` in place of `getch` the problem disappears. But I cant use `gets` because I want the user to hit a single key without needing to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after the key to give input. 
For example `flag` should not change when the user inputs <kbd>a</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> and so I have used `getch` to make sure the input is given after a single keyboard hit.

A similar problem was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232924/get-line-feed-with-getch-in-ruby) but it isn't a duplicate.

**Edit 1:**
The problem seems to be with `getch` and not the check what do ever.

```
flag = 0

t2 =Thread.new do
  puts flag

  loop do
    temp = STDIN.getch
    flag = (flag+1)%2
    puts flag
  end

end
t2.join
```

Even after removing the if statement, the first <kbd>Enter</kbd> is ignored no matter what but other characters seem to respond to the first time. The problem is coming only when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It doesn't count the first <kbd>Enter</kbd> I hit.

```
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code on a Windows machine and was able to re-create the problem. As you correctly guessed it has nothing to do with threading and everything with how `getch` works (on Windows).
If you add a `p temp.inspect` to your loop you will see that it is not so much that the first '\n' is swallowed, rather it is that it is somehow "held back". The best way to see this if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and another key alternatively. You will see that the inspect is "off-by-one".

A good explanation about the problem is discussed here:
https://www.rubytapas.com/2016/12/14/ruby-code-on-windows/

With that information, a simple solution (that has the added benefit to run also on Linux, not sure about Mac) is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'io/console'

STDIN.binmode     #this line added to prevent line-end translation

flag = 0
t2 =Thread.new do
    puts flag
    loop do
        temp = STDIN.getch
        if temp=="\r"  # note: changed from LF to CR
            flag = (flag+1)%2
            puts flag
        end
    end
end

# => Some foreground code

t2.join
```

Notes:
Admittedly I don't fully get the way it works. I was expecting that <kbd>Enter</kbd> would cause a "\r\n" sequence in binmode, but I only see "\r". Not sure what happens to the "\n", but it seems to work reliably this way.
Also note that in the current version the program can not be terminated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. You'll have to add a check for that.

Comment: Really helped. ty